# check if something is divisble by 3

Tags: c

i have something to read a text file, and then a function file like this

```
int Myiseven(int x)
{
    int isOdd = 0;
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
        isOdd = 1;
    }
}
```

so that all odd numbers would have isodd = 1

how would i go about checking if a number is divisible by three

the original main file is this

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE


#include<stdio.h>
#include "ProblemHeader_4.h"
int main()
{
    FILE *myfile = fopen("input.txt", "w");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 33; i++)
    {
        fprintf(myfile, "%d\n", i);
    }
    fclose(myfile);

    FILE *myfileRead = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE *myfileWrite = fopen("outputEven.txt", "w");

    int readBuff;
    while (!feof(myfileRead))
    {
        fscanf(myfileRead, "%d", &readBuff);
        printf("These numbers were read: %d\n", readBuff);

        int isOdd = Myiseven(readBuff);
        if (isOdd == 1)
        {
            fprintf(myfileWrite, "%d\n", readBuff);
            printf("This number is divisible by 3: %d\n", readBuff);
        }
    }
    fclose(myfileWrite);
    fclose(myfileRead);

    return 0;
}
```

and header

```
#ifndef MY_VAR
#define MY_VAR

#include<stdio.h>

int Myiseven(int x);

#endif
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried doing? You seem to know the modulo operator `%` already  2. Your `Myiseven` function exhibits *undefined behavior* because it is missing a `return` statement

Comment: You know about the modulo operator `%`. I suggest you experiment with it. For example `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { printf("%d % 3 = %d\n", i, i % 3) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you only want to print odd numbers that are divisible by 3. You can do  this as follows:

```
if (isOdd == 1 && readBuff%3==0)
        {
            fprintf(myfileWrite, "%d\n", readBuff);
            printf("This number is divisible by 3: %d\n", readBuff);
        }
```

Additionally, you need a `return` statement in `Myiseven()` function in order to execute your code successfully:

```
int Myiseven(int x)
{
    int isOdd = 0;
    if (x % 2 == 1) {
        isOdd = 1;
    }
   return isOdd;
}
```

Comment: thanks, was trying to get any number divisible by 3 but i changed it and it works now :)

Comment: if you want to check for all number than no need to check for `isOdd==1`